# How to make a multiline timeline with consecutive elements with Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, timeline

I am asking this question for Excel because that would seem like something it could do but I am open to using other mac-compatible software.

What I am trying to do is a basically list of leaders for several countries. Horizontally is time. Vertically is the list of countries and, for each country, bars will display each leader from the beginning to the end of his mandate.

Ideally, I would just have a table with the leader's name, mandate dates and country, and all this would be plotted on the graph, allowing for easy modifications by just adding someone or changing the dates.

Unfortunately, all I find so far gives me one line per leader or the different blocks need to be of the same "category" for all the lines. So I've started just merging cells manually but, since I'm doing this for many countries and several decades, I'm dealing with over 600 cells and it's a looooot of manual work. So I'd be very happy to have a way to just input the dates.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Any idea if that's possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is the OP and I am answering my own question.

- For the sake of clarity, I got a worksheet per country; each one listing the leader's name, beginning and ending date, and duration (actually, you can use the end date of one leader and have a formula to automatically use is as beginning time for the next; duration is a subtraction between the two, in number for).
- Then I have one worksheet with a major table: one row per country
  (for me about 50) and one line per leader. That's a lot of lines but
  I copy them from the individual country worksheets, which means that
  when the work is done there, it's just copy-paste. So I copy the
  leaders' names and the duration in the column of the matching
  country. Overall, a country's column with only have the duration data
  for its own leaders, the rest is blank.
- Since I arbitrarily start my data collection on 01/01/1960, the trick
  is to add the initial date in number form to the first leader's
  duration. That way his "duration" includes all the time until
  01/01/1960 plus his actual time in power; since the graph start at
  01/01/1960, it hides the first part, leaving only the proper duration
  after 01/01/1960. Following leaders have their own duration.
- That's about it. Now a last worksheet has a giant horizontal bar
  graph that has time as X and countries as Y, so one line (or
  timeline) per country that has all the names of the leaders.
- The only thing left for me to adjust at this point as the colours of
  the bars on the graph, as Excel strives to use unique colours and so
  they get extremely pale.

I hope this helps for future reference!

[Screen caps of worksheets for individual countries and major table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzMoD.png)

[Screen cap of bar graph (with colour issue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpTFe.png)